# Can I hide info.plist in a kext? or can I dynamic create info.plist?

Tags: xcode, kernel, driver, kernel-extension, info-plist

Can I hide info.plist in a kext? or can I dynamic create info.plist for a kext?

I have a codeless kext where it only has info.plist, however, I dont want to expose info.plist to everybody so they can simply just copy my codes... so I was thinking either hide the info.plist or dynamically create info.plist while driver is loading or encrypt the entire kext?

Comment: In short: no. But if you tell us what you're really trying to achieve with this, then maybe we can make an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, pmdj. I have a codeless kext where it only has info.plist, however, I dont want to expose info.plist to everybody so they can simply just copy my codes... so I was thinking either hide the info.plist or dynamically create info.plist while driver is loading or encrypt the entire kext? Thanks.

Comment: @CastAway1970: It is better to **add this information into the question itself**. Note, that *answer post* may give answer only for the *question*, it cannot answer a *comments*.

Comment: Thanks, Tsyvarev, I did not know I could edit my original question. Thanks.

Comment: What information in the Info.plist are you expecting to hide?

Answer (score 0):

You can't encrypt/obfuscate the Info.plist itself. It is part of the code signing process and requirement though, so it's not trivially modifiable.

You don't state it specifically, but I'm assuming there's some property in the I/O Kit Personality dictionary that you want to hide? Those properties can equivalently be set from code, specifically in the `init()` function of your driver class, unless they're required for matching. Note that any properties you've set are world-readable in the I/O Kit Registry at runtime though, so I suspect this isn't what you want.

If the information you're trying to hide is part of the matching conditions, for example you're attempting to hide product IDs of thus-far unreleased devices, you can, depending on your driver family's matching rules, probably implement this logic in code in the `probe()` function. I wouldn't make the matching rules in the Info.plist too broad though, or your kext will be loaded every time e.g. a provider with the given provider class turns up. This is unnecessarily inefficient.

Obviously, in both cases, your kext will no longer be codeless, but you can obfuscate to your heart's content in the C++/C/assembly code.

If you want a more specific answer than that, you'll need to be more specific in your question.